# How to backup and restore a sparse file on ESXi

Tags: filesystems, esxi

I've a thin provisioned virtual disk (500 GB) on an ESXi server (version 7.0.3) which I'd like to backup to an external USB disk and afterwards to restore it on another ESXi server.
The effective size of the file of this virtual disk is only 50 GB (#du -ah). However, if I copy this file (sparse file) to an external USB disk, this file will occupy 500 GB on the external USB disk and I'm afraid that if I copy this file from the external USB disk to another ESXi server, it will also occupy 500 GB there and not only 50 GB, won't it?

So my question; is there a smart way to backup such sparse files on an external USB disk so that they only occupy the effective space (50 GB instead of 500 GB) and then restore them to another ESXi server so they're available there again as sparse files?